# Linear programming for Optimization

Tags: optimization, glpk

I am faced with an Optimization problem. I have used GLPK solver for this. However I noticed GNU license prevents it from being used in Commercial Software. Since i have already done my part of coding what other options (other than GLPK) do i have to re-implement the said problem with minimal changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX and Gurobi are commercial solvers. If your solution depends on the GMPL language have a look at AMPL which provides a similar language.